# Solr performance issues with negative queries

Tags: solr, solr4

Queries in Solr are taking too much, sometimes even more than 4 seconds on high load. The issues is I want to negative ids and when this number reaches 4000-5000 than my search becomes very slow.
Cases when i need these high negative number:
In searches if we don't show ignore list which is mostly varies from 100 to 30k.

My overall size of solr is a million documents

What all optimization solution can we use?
1. one can be optimzing solr which i had never used
http://[HostName]:[port]/solr/update?optimize=true

Will above help?

Also can someone suggest for handling large negative ids in solr?

Comment: Please use international units (10lacs == 1 million). Instead of filtering by a large number of ids - can you attach a separate field like `excluded_from` in a document with "KEY_FOR_MY_SEARCH" and filter against that? Calling `optimize` will merge all your index segments to a single segment (or the number of segments you've configured iirc), which might be useful if you're not updating the index very often. Whether it'll help should be very easy to test, just optimize the index and run the queries against it - shouldn't take too long.

Comment: There has been a lot of performance improvements in Solr 6. Especially related to long Id lists. May be worth trying the latest version.

Comment: @MatsLindh adding excluded_from will be too expensive and i need to update solr almost 20times/seconds and even more.